# Почему Ubuntu не запускает ./Prepros программу?

Tags: ubuntu

Помогите решить вопрос с использованием Prepros в Kubuntu.

При запуске из оболочки все функции работают нормально, кроме Live Preview. Появляется сообщение "Установлено соединение с localhost". И все зависает пока не отменить.

При запуске из консоли ничего не происходит.

```
$ sudo ./Prepros 
[sudo] пароль для oem: 
(electron) ipc module is deprecated. Use require("electron").ipcMain instead.
(electron) app.getDataPath is deprecated. Use app.getPath instead.
```

Как исправить? В чем причина?

Comment: а sudo вы пишете для «связки слов в предложении»?

Comment: Строки, начинающиеся с `(electron)` явно не `sudo` выводит, так что `Prepros` у вас запустилась.

Answer (score 1):

> При запуске из консоли ничего не происходит.
>   `$ sudo ./Prepros`

собственно, ничего и не должно происходить.

вы же пытаетесь выполнить программу, которой надо нарисовать (как минимум одно) «окно» с помощью [*x-сервера*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), но при этом запуская её от **имени другого пользователя** (в данному случае — пользователя *root*).

другому пользователю, естественно, не удастся подключиться к вашей *x-сессии*.

да, в принципе, можно предоставить другому пользователю такую возможность хотя бы на время работы текущей *x-сессии*, но в данном случае в этом нет ни малейшей необходимости. просто выполняйте программу от **вашего** имени:

```
$ ./Prepros
```